# fileschanged daemon dies unexpectedly

Tags: bash, services, monitoring

I'm using [fileschanged](http://fileschanged.sourceforge.net/) to monitor files on `server1` and run a Bash script to sync the files in `server1` to `server2` if any of the files are changed in `server1`. To do that I'm running this:

```
fileschanged -r -s "created,changed" --exec="/home/ccc/sync.sh" -f /var/www/html < /dev/null &
```

The script runs as a daemon and whenever I change a file in the specified folder, `synch.sh` is executed. The problem is after a while (hours) the daemon dies. It can't be found in `ps -ax` and of course doesn't execute `synch.sh` when a change happens. What could be the cause of this behaviour? Why would a daemonized script die? Is there a log somewhere I could check for the reason?

Comment: hu? - here is a link ... http://superuser.com/questions/189286/tool-to-run-a-command-when-file-changed and there is a comment of tomas with a command to use inotify or notify ... ? does this help ?

Comment: No. Thats not the question. I know how to monitor with fileschanged

Comment: Wrap it in a script that runs `fileschanged ...` and, when `fileschanged` exits, logs the event (`man logger`). Put the script in the background.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to do that, can you provide me the code for the script?